# How to enumerate a Format-Table entry in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have an array of hashes, and I want that array to be formatted as a table with each entry enumerated without actually adding a hash item to contain this information.  E.g.

```
$id = 0
$items = @( @{ item='a' }, @{ item='b' }, @{ item='c' })
$items |
 %{ new-object PSObject -Property $_ } |
  Format-Table @{ n=""; e={ "{0}" -f ++$id }; a="left" },item
```

I'm expecting:

```
  item
- ----
1 a   
2 b   
3 c
```

but getting:

```
  item
- ----
1 a   
1 b   
1 c
```

Comment: Is this basically a line number? What relevance does the number have? It doesn't interact with your hash at all, and since you're outputting it as a string, it doesn't seem to be used for anything other than a line number.

Comment: @BenjaminHubbard, you are correct sir.  That is what I was trying to accomplish.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with @Adrian's answer but it is really just a scope issue. So if you explicitly scope the variable to the SCRIPT scope inside the format code then it will work as well.

Comment: @EBGreen, that's interesting, I had tried `local` scope when I was within a function, but it didn't work.  Looks like it is local to within the expression.  Using `global` scope does work, but puts the variable in the global scope which I don't like.  I'd like to scope it within the function that I wrap around this code fragment.

Comment: @EBGreen, had actually meant `script` not `global` scope but same result. The variable is then placed in a scope where it has no business being.  Not exactly sure why I couldn't using numbered scope.  Seems to be some sort of barrier keeping me from accessing the scope of the calling function.  Maybe because this is a callback?

Answer (score 3):

Seems that the `$id` is passed by value.  Need to force it as a reference using `[ref]` and it'll work.  E.g.:

```
[ref]$id = 0
$items = @( @{ item='a' }, @{ item='b' }, @{ item='c' })
$items | %{ new-object PSObject -Property $_ } |
 Format-Table @{ n=""; e={ "{0}" -f ++$id.value }; a="left" },item
```